# Regex to match with digit in the string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, string

I will have a different type of string(string will not have fixed format,they will be different every time) from them I want to remove some specific substring.Like the string can be

```
OPTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY CE 2500
OPTIDX NIFTY 30 Jul 2009 4600.00 PE
OPTSTK ICICIBANK 30 Jul 2009 700.00 PA
```

I want to extract Rs.(digit) from those string and store it into one variable and then in those string there should not be Rs.(digit).

What should be the regex for that ?

**EDIT**

```
private string ExtractingRupeesFromString(String str)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(cellRecord, @"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*$");
    return match.Value.ToString();
}

for(int i=0;i<datagridview1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    datagridview1["Rs",i].Value=ExtractingRupeesFromString(datagridview1["ScriptName",i].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to extract only ['2500', '4600.00', '700.00'], you could use following regex with MULTILINE flag enabled

```
@"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*$"
```

**Edit**: Added optional [+-], and some C# codes

```
string s = @"
OPTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY CE 2500
OPTIDX NIFTY 30 Jul 2009 4600.00 PE
OPTSTK ICICIBANK 30 Jul 2009 700.00 PA
";
Regex re = new Regex(@"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*$",RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match a in re.Matches(s)){
    System.Console.WriteLine(a.Groups[1]);
}

//2500
//4600.00
//700.00
```

**Edit**:

You could change

```
return match.Value.ToString();
```

to

```
return match.Groups[1].ToString();
```

to return only number part.

Comment: @S.Mark,How is `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+` ?

Comment: @Harikrishna, ok, if there is + or - infront of those, thats good idea. but `[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` would be better, because decimal part could be ignored.

Comment: @Harikrishna, do you use the one in my c# example? `@"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*$"`

Comment: @S.Mark,But it matches with `-1300.00`.

Comment: @Harikrishna, `-1300.00` is matched because `[+-]?` , if `-` or `+` is not need , remove `[+-]?`

Comment: @Harikrishna, `\D*$` is to match `PA` after `1300.00` and to make sure to match *last* numeric value in a certain line. If you remove those parts, 2009 and other numbers will match, so its not good idea to remove those parts.

Comment: @Harikrishna, make sure you use `Groups[1]` to match only `1300.00` instead of `1300.00 PA`

Comment: @S.Mark,Then any other approach to let do not match with `PA`.

Comment: @S.Mark,Sir I am checking it one by one not by groups.

Comment: @Harikrishna, can I see the code you using? and a little more details? You could update it in question or could post another one, if the question is different.

Answer (score 1):

How is

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+");
Rupees=str.Substring(match.Index,match.Length);
```

Is it ok ? Please check the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jack30lena. This can be easy done with an regular expression.

for example:

```
Regex blabla = new Regex(@"([^0-9]*(?<number>[0-9])+)*");
MatchCollection matches = blabla.matches("OPTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY CE 2500");
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
string number = m.Groups["number"].Value;
//do something with the match...
}
```